# Square with two vertices on $x$ axis and the other on a function

Tags: functions

Suppose that the function $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and positive at interior points and vanishes at the ends. Show that there exists a square whose two vertices lie on the $x$-axis, and the other two on the graph $y = f(x)$.Is it because the ends of function vanish meaning they go to infinity? That would mean the function has an infection point and thus by ivt has two points that create a horizontal line on $f$?

Comment: No, vanish usually means "equal to zero".

Comment: Aha if it goes to zero at the ends which means it's easier then I thought ?? Or maybe ..

Comment: It means the function is a parabola?

Comment: A parabola would work, but it doesn't have to be. A "mountain range", that has multiple peaks but is at "sea level" at each end, would also be possible.

Comment: I haven't solved it, but I would assume the left end point on the x axis is at position x, and then write down the equation (involving your function f) that would mean there is a square satisfying the claim positioned there. Then I'd hope there is some sort of MVT argument that would guarantee there exists an x that satisfies it, given what you know happens at the end point. (You probably wouldn't apply MVT to f, but to some other function related to f.)

Comment: Consider the function $f(x + f(x)) - f(x)$.